# Processing of Converting the html to PDF takes a lot of time by using DinkToPdf library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, html-to-pdf, dinktopdf

Processing of Converting the html to PDF takes a long time by using `DinkToPdf` library, when this line of code runs: `ConverterToPdf.Convert(pdf)`

How can I solve this problem?

```
public byte[] ConvertReportToPDFAsync<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : new()
{
   var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
   {
      ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
      Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
      PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
      Margins = new MarginSettings { Top = 10 },
      DocumentTitle = documentTitle,
   };

   var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
   {
      PagesCount = true,
      HtmlContent =@"<html><body><div>Hello</div></body></html>",
      WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf -8", UserStyleSheet = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets", "PruefReportDataTableFormat.css") },
      HeaderSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = true },
      FooterSettings = { FontName = "Arial", FontSize = 9, Line = true, Center = "Report Footer" }
    };
    var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
    {
       GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
       Objects = { objectSettings }
    };

   byte[] file = ConverterToPdf.Convert(pdf); // TOO LONG PROCESS !!!!

   return file;

}
```

**Startup class:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); 
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMemoryCache(); services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools())); // DinkToPdf
    }
}
```

> Updated:

**After tracing, I figured out the problem is in** `WkHtmlToXBindings.wkhtmltopdf_convert` **method in** `namespace DinkToPdf`

```
namespace DinkToPdf
{
   public sealed class PdfTools : ITools, IDisposable
   {
      // some codes
      public bool DoConversion(IntPtr converter)
      {
         return WkHtmlToXBindings.wkhtmltopdf_convert(converter); // ACTUALLY TOO LONG PROCESS OCCURS HERE !!!!
      }
   }
}
```

> Update 2:

**After deep tracing, I figured out that in this line of code,** `Monitor.Wait((object) task1);`**, occurred long process!**
(I cannot change this code, because this code is part of `dinktopdf.dll` file.)

```
namespace DinkToPdf
{
   public class SynchronizedConverter : BasicConverter
   {
      public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> @delegate)
      {
         this.StartThread();
         Task<TResult> task1 = new Task<TResult>(@delegate);
         Task<TResult> task2 = task1;
         bool lockTaken = false;
         try
         {
             Monitor.Enter((object) task2, ref lockTaken);
             this.conversions.Add((Task) task1);
             Monitor.Wait((object) task1);   //Bottleneck!! LONG PROCESS!!
         }
         finally
         {
            if (lockTaken)
               Monitor.Exit((object) task2);
         }
         if (task1.Exception != null)
            throw task1.Exception;
         return task1.Result;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what's the `ConverterToPdf` in this line `byte[] file = ConverterToPdf.Convert(pdf);` ? Is it an instance of `IConverter` injected by DI ? I've tried your code.  Assuming the `ConverterToPdf` is a standard instance injected by DI, it works well for me.  If there's a demo that reproduces ?

Comment: Yes!  It is an instance of IConverter injected by DI. public IConverter ConverterToPdf

Comment: Is there's a demo that produces the same issue?

Comment: There is no demo.

Comment: Just I thought but these are bindings to an unmanaged library doing the actual conversion. Could it be antivirus related?

Comment: It's not related to antivirus.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "long time"?

Comment: for creating a simple pdf, it takes more than 3 minutes time.

Comment: SynchronizedConverter blocks and processes one operation at a time. This might be a source of bottlenecks. Can you try BasicConverter with a single request only?

Comment: byte[] file = null;
            using (var pdfTools = new PdfTools())
            {
                var converter = new BasicConverter(pdfTools);
                file = converter.Convert(pdf);
            }



That was not useful!

Comment: Why do you say you cannot change the code? it's open source (plus your code doesn't seem to match the github repo https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/blob/b0546d21641eaef71f6fe0ddfd3998e8502baab7/src/DinkToPdf/SynchronizedConverter.cs ...)

Comment: Are you bound to DinkToPdf?

Comment: I use only the dll file, but when I debugging, Resharper can show the classes for DinkToPdf.dll during the debug.

Comment: Do you absolutely want to use this library ? I use another and it's very fast : [Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore)

Comment: @LoïcSombart Are you satisfied with Rotativa? Is it compatible with asp.net core 2.2

Comment: @Jahan I use Rotativa with asp.net core 2.0. There are a few configurations lines and a file (.exe) to add in your project folder. Then it automatically transforms a view (.cshtml) into PDF. If you are interested or you have a configuration problem, I will put an answer.

Comment: @LoïcSombart Thanks! I will Test it tomorrow.

Comment: If you are going to test Rotativa take a look at https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp, build upon the chrome-renderer.

Comment: @LoïcSombart: I got this error after installing. CS0246 C# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Jahan Have you installed Rotativa.AspNetCore version 1.1.1 by Giorgio Bozio ?

Comment: @LoïcSombart: I solved it. But now I want to configure it. I will tell you the result.

Comment: @LoïcSombart: How can I set the path of cshtml file? for example I want to show contain of ViewComponent and it located in \\Views\MyController\Components\MyViewComponent\Default.cshtml

Comment: @Jahan, directly in the method of your controller : `return new ViewAsPdf(viewName)`

Comment: @LoïcSombart: Suppose! I have a controller and in this controller there is a search button and select-option. It depends on, I get various result that call their ViewComponent. And now I want to save the result of ViewComponet as Pdf.

Comment: @Jahan Either you make a condition with several Return, or you can pass objects in your view with `return new ViewAsPdf(viewName, object)`.
I have PdfController > method Site() > return new ViewAsPdf("Site")
and my view is in Views/Pdf/Site.cshtml.
I hope it will help you.

Comment: I call a ViewComponent in my view of controller. like this: <div>
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("PlakettenabrechnungReport", Model)
                </div>

Comment: @Jahan what's the error with your code ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a singleton you created on your Startup.cs so what you need to do firstly is to populate your root object with dependency injection.

```
private readonly IConverter _converter;

public YourControllerService(IConverter converter)
{            
    _converter = converter            
}

public void CreatePdf() {
    byte[] bytes = _converter.Convert(doc);
}
```

Secondly, make sure that you use **web safe fonts** to speed up the rendering. Using fonts from external urls inside your html will slow down the process. For instance, lets say this is your html template and your have 5 pages:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,700');
        body {
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        }
    <style>
<head>
</html>
```

if you change this with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>         
        body {
            font-family: 'Verdana'; 
        }
    <style>
<head>
</html>
```

you will see the speed difference. Also, according to my experience reducing the DPI also effects the rendering speed.

```
var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
{
    GlobalSettings = {
        ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
        Orientation = Orientation.Landscape,
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
        DPI = 320,
        Out = path
    },
    Objects = {
        new ObjectSettings() {                               
            PagesCount = true,
            HtmlContent = html,
            WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "UTF-8", LoadImages = true },
            FooterSettings = { FontSize = 8, Right = "Page [page] of [toPage]", Line = false, Spacing = 2.812 }
        }
    }
};

byte[] bytes = _converter.Convert(doc);
```

Hope there help.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how you get `ConverterToPdf`, but you can try this: If you initialize converter with `var converter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());´, remove it, and just inject`IConverter` in your service.

I tried and this approach is working, after all, we already register the converter, we don't need to create an instance using the  `new` keyword.

Comment: @gehbiszumeis, Thank you for your help, and sorry for my English and not properly formatted comment!